Multiple comparisons and explanation of two-factor experiment
I am doing investigation with temperature and accession on trait of plants with R.
Temperature: 25/20, 30/25, 35/30
Accession: V9,BTx623, 2-16-6, 1-10-4, 2-16-6, 19-22-12
The interaction and Temperature and Accession are all significant.
Here is my code and my output:
lm.hd = lm(HD~Temperature+Accession+Accession*Temperature, data = df1)
summary(lm.hd, digits = 2)

Coefficients:
Temperature30/25:Accession19-22-12 -14.4667     5.1797  -2.793  0.00710 ** 
Temperature35/30:Accession19-22-12 -26.1500     5.7496  -4.548 2.88e-05 ***
Temperature30/25:Accession2-16-6    -0.5167     4.8452  -0.107  0.91545    
Temperature35/30:Accession2-16-6    -4.9500     5.7496  -0.861  0.39288    
Temperature30/25:Accession6-13-19   -4.5167     5.3167  -0.850  0.39914 

There is no effect of 25/20:1-10-4,30/25:1-10-4,35/30:1-10-4, 1-10-4,25/20...because its effect is the effect reference point, so they are 0.But when I want to do multiple comparison. I found these reference point are compared:
model<-aov(HD~Temperature+Accession+Accession*Temperature, data = df1)
hsd = TukeyHSD(model, conf.level=.95)
$`Temperature:Accession`
                                     diff          lwr         upr     p adj
30/25:1-10-4-25/20:1-10-4      -5.4000000 -17.78670947   6.9867095 0.9771241
35/30:1-10-4-25/20:1-10-4       3.2000000 -13.18607642  19.5860764 0.9999992
25/20:19-22-12-25/20:1-10-4     5.4000000  -6.98670947  17.7867095 0.9771241
30/25:19-22-12-25/20:1-10-4   -14.4666667 -28.76960677  -0.1637266 0.0446504
35/30:19-22-12-25/20:1-10-4   -17.5500000 -30.68808940  -4.4119106 0.0011157
25/20:2-16-6-25/20:1-10-4      10.9500000  -2.18808940  24.0880894 0.2144087
30/25:2-16-6-25/20:1-10-4       5.0333333  -6.82603809  16.8927048 0.9822835
35/30:2-16-6-25/20:1-10-4       9.2000000  -3.18670947  21.5867095 0.3952535
**25/20:6-13-19-25/20:1-10-4     18.8666667   4.56372657  33.1696068 0.0013738**
30/25:6-13-19-25/20:1-10-4      8.9500000  -4.18808940  22.0880894 0.5481008
35/30:6-13-19-25/20:1-10-4      8.2000000  -4.18670947  20.5867095 0.5976845
25/20:BTx623-25/20:1-10-4      27.4000000  15.01329053  39.7867095 0.0000000
30/25:BTx623-25/20:1-10-4      15.8666667   1.56372657  30.1696068 0.0160463
35/30:BTx623-25/20:1-10-4      21.7000000   5.31392358  38.0860764 0.0012876
25/20:V9-25/20:1-10-4          -1.9666667 -13.82603809   9.8927048 0.9999999

** is the place I am really confused. And also are there proper way to show these effect and the comparison result?

What is confusing about the ** part?
In your multiple comparisons, you are now comparing each paired combination of each of your predictors with each other paired combination. E.g. whether "Temperature 30/25 paired with Accession 1-10-4" differs from "Temperature 25/20 paired with Accession 2-16-6".
Maybe that's what you want - in which case you can base your report on the comparisons you posted and write up which comparisons were significant and which were not (I'd rename the levels of factors to something easier to understand for your report) and interpret those results as usual.
It's customary to present the means in visual form and report the important statistics in a table (e.g. means, difference contrast (diff in your output), their confidence intervals (lwr and upr in your output) and the p-value (p adj in your output).
However, usually people don't want all possible comparisons from an interaction. Maybe you'd like to see whether differences between Temperature levels are different within Accession 19-22-12 than what they are within Accession 2-16-6 etc.? In that case, try for instance
library(emmeans)
em<-emmeans(lm.hd, ~ Accession*Temperature)
contrast(em, pairwise, simple = "each", combine=T, adjust="sidak") 

#default p-value adjustment is Bonferroni which is quite strict, this gives you the comparisons with Sidak adjustment.


My confusion is that the Coefficients of some levels did not show in summary(lm.hd, digits = 2), like 25/20:1-10-4 and 35/30:1-10-4 are 0, but TukeyHSD(model, conf.level=.95) still can compare, or did I misunderstand it?

lm(summary) gives you the intercept (which is the mean of outcome when all predictors are at their reference levels) and each predictor's non-reference levels' deviations from the reference level. So, it only gives you other levels' differences from the reference level. Multiple comparisons, obtained through functions such as TukeyHSD or emmeans give you all comparisons between all levels of predictors, as you see in your multiple comparisons output. Post-hoc comparisons also include reference levels.
